# Defining value according a specific value at memory location

Tags: c, gcc, stm32

I have an issue with defining value according a specific value at memory location.

Basically I want to read a value at specific memory location and create a define from this value. And then use this same define to define again a new value according the first define value when compiling the code.

Here is my example:

```
#define MY_DEFINE_VALUE         (*(uint32_t *)0x0800C200)

// 8 kBytes of EEPROM
// First section base address is 0x08080000
// Second section base address is 0x08081000
#if ( MY_DEFINE_VALUE < 0x0200 )
#define EEPROM_BASE                             ((uint32_t)0x08080000)
#else 
#define EEPROM_BASE                             ((uint32_t)0x08081000)
#endif
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're dereferencing an address. That can't be done at preprocessing time.

Comment: The expression `*(uint32_t *)0x0800C200` must be evaluated at *run-time*. The preprocessor is a pure *compile-time* thing. You can't mix the two.

Comment: the machine you're compiling this isn't even the target right?

Comment: No the machine where I'm compiling isn't the target to execute the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solve this in that way, C doesn't work like that. In fact it makes no sense, since you're expecting there two be two different pieces of code in the same place (one that uses `0x08080000` and one that uses `0x08081000`).

You're going to have to:

1. Build two different binaries, and program the board accordingly. This pushes the responsibility for knowing which board needs which binary to outside the software
2. Check at run-time, and either pick between hardcoded alternatives of the code, or simply do make the access dynamic.

My preference would be dynamic run-time access, which should be fine unless this is in the most performance-critical part of your code.

So, you'd make a variable:

```
volatile uint32_t *eeprom_base;
```

and then just add code to set it at run-time:

```
if (*(uint32_t *) 0x800c200 < 0x200)
  eeprom_base = (uint32_t *) 0x8080000;
else
  eeprom_base = (uint32_t *) 0x8081000;
```

then make the accesses through the variable instead of the preprocessor symbol, or change the latter to:

```
#define EEPROM_BASE    eeprom_base
```

Of course you're going to have to make sure the variable has a visible declaration in all places where it's being used, too.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution even if I need to change a lot of things :(